# Why is cache control not working?

Tags: html, caching, meta-tags, metatag

I set the cache control to "no-cache" and "max-age=0" still when I click on back button of the browser it shows the  previous page. Actually the problem is when we login from login page and then it gets login to the main page but if we hit back button then it again shows the login page.Thats why i want to apply cache-control to no-cache but it is not working. Is there any other option to do it. What I've done is as follows
I added these two meta-tag to head section of page :

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disableing cache is covered well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: Actually the problem is when we login and then it gets login to the main page but if we hit back button then it again shows the login page.

Comment: So detail the problem in your question.

Comment: Thats why i want to apply cache-control to no-cache but it is not working

Comment: Cache control doesn't control navigation. It makes the browser download the page again.

Comment: ok thats fine. i just do it.

Comment: so is there any other way to do it

Comment: This question should be fixed or deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in one of my javascript project, please pick this code if useful to resolve your issue, this is one of the way to handle browser back button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward();
        function noBack(){
            window.history.forward();
        }
</script>

<body onload="noBack();">
```

Comment: but this script is working only for chrome not for other browsers.

Comment: there could be a conflict with other functions please debug, for me it worked in all webkit browsers even IE.

Comment: Try adding this <body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">

Comment: The problem is if the user disables JS.